# How to disable the use of shorthands in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My bibliographic database contains pre-set shorthands for some items. However, sometimes I have to use the numeric citation style and the pre-set shorthands end up overriding the numeric labels. Is there a way to avoid this without modifying the bibliographic database?

Comment: Do you happen to use Biber?

Comment: Yes, I am using Biber.

Comment: I'll be back with a solution shortly. But just to be sure I understood you correctly, do you have a `label` or a `shorthand` field in the relevant `.bib` entries? (A MWE would really help me to come up with an adequate solution quicker.)

Comment: I am using the `shorthand` field, not the `label` field.

Comment: OK, I can get rid off all `shorthand`s. Is that fine with you?

Comment: If you could post an answer that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one does not want to use a `sourcemap` definition, it is possible to nullify the values of  the `shorthand` (or other fields) using
`\DeclareFieldInputHandler`

Here the value of  the field is read from the `.bbl` file (so after it has been generated by `biber`)

```
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{shorthand}{\def\NewValue{}}
```

Comment: This seems like the more flexible approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to get rid of the `shorthand` to make sure the label is just a normal numeric one, you can go with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This makes sure the `shorthand` is ignored by Biber before it comes to label generation.
(An `\AtEveryCitekey` approach can not work here.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{kant:kpv}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```