# Variable family name (\mkbibnamefamily) depending on entry type in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

So I'm using the `french` language with a style derived from `authortitle-terse`. I've tried to ask an [ambitious (too ambitious?) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428903/cross-ref-of-book-in-series-or-book-citing-child-should-makes-both-child-and-p) here, and I'm trying to break down this question in sub-piece.

Now, I'd like to customize the style of the author family name, depending on the type of the entry. From my previous experience and question here, I cannot find how to do it.

In the `french.lbx`, I read that the `\mkbibnamefamily` is defined as:

```
  \protected\def\mkbibnamefamily#1{%
    \textsc{\textnohyphenation{#1}}}%
```

So as far as I know, and [based on my first tries here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426387/custom-style-breaks-the-cite-command), I could not do something like:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{\mkbibnamefamily}{#1}
```

Or even:

```
\UndefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\renewcommand[article, book]{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
```

Because the last line on article/book breaks the code.

## Questions

1. How can I change the formatting of family names by type of entry?
2. What is the formatting of names so different than the `\DeclareFieldFormat` for title?
3. What would be the command to format the family name of an editor?

## MWE Code

**`main.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

% Needed by Biblatex
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}    
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-terse, language=french, bibencoding=UTF8, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{main.bib}    
    \DeclareFieldFormat{author}{#1}% no postnote prefix in "multicite" commands
\UndefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
% \renewcommand[article, book]{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}    

\begin{document}
\section{Test de la bibliographie}
\printbibliography
\section{Tests de citation}
book : \cite{book} \\
thesis : \cite{thesis} \\
Article : \cite{article} \\
\end{document}
```

**`main.bib`**

```
@book{book,
    author      = {Other, Nicolas},
    title       = {A title for a thesis},
    date        = {2017},
    location    = {Berne and Bâle and Lugano},
    origlocation = {Lausanne}
}

@thesis{thesis,
  author      = {Gut, Nicolas},
  title       = {Die unbezifferte Forderungsklage nach der Schweizerischen Zivilprozessordnung},
  location    = {Bâle},
  date        = {2014},
}

@article{article,
  author      = {Affolter, Markus},
  title       = {Die Durchsetzunh von Informationspflichten im Zivilprozess},
  origLocation    = {St. Gall},
  date        = {1994},
  location    = {Berne and Stuttgart and Vienne},
}
```

Comment: For name fields, you need to use `\DeclareNameFormat`

Comment: It's just a typo, but if you have the `Affolter` citation in your real `.bib` file you may want to make sure it reads `Durchsetzung` (with `g` instead of `Durchsetzunh`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For type-specific formatting in `\mkbibnamefamily` you can use `\ifentrytype`.

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
     \ifentrytype{article}
       {\mkbibemph{#1}}
       {\textsc{#1}}}
   ```

   This issue is complicated by the fact that your document loads the French localisation. `french.lbx` redefines `\mkbibnamefamily` to always give small caps. You can tell `french.lbx` to stop messing about with `\mkbibnamefamily` with

   ```
   \DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
   ```
2. `biblatex` roughly knows three data types: (1) fields, (2) lists and (3) name lists. Fields are the simplest of the bunch and can be completely customised with `\DeclareFieldFormat`. Lists are a bit more tricky since a list may contain an arbitrary number of items and you may want to format the entire list as one chunk or the items separately. Additionally, `biblatex` needs a bit of work to place the delimiters between items of a list. The customisation command for lists is `\DeclareListFormat`. Names are even more tricky, they are not only lists, but the items of the list are made up of name parts, which warrant special treatment. The command for name lists is `\DeclareNameFormat`, but there are many helper macros such as `\mkbibnamefamily` to help you customise name formats without actually using `\DeclareNameFormat`. All the `\Declare...Format` commands can be made type-specific with an optional first argument. The helper commands for names are in general not type-specific, but one can work around that (as see above).
3. That depends on the exact context. You could use `\ifcurrentname{editor}{<true>}{<false>}` just like `\ifentrytype{article}{<true>}{<false>}` in item 1. You could also define a completely new name format. To understand how that would work, let's walk through `biblatex.def`'s definitions for `author` (note that the standard definitions of `biblatex.def` are slightly modified if you use `authoryear`- or `authortitle`-like styles, they set `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}` instead, but the principle is the same and the code is shorter with the standard `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}`).

   The name format for `author` is defined with

   ```
   \DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
   ```

   we later find

   ```
   \DeclareNameAlias{default}{given-family}
   ```

   and then

   ```
   \DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
     \ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
   ```

   This means that name formats involve calling helper macros. The most important macro here is `name:given-family`

   ```
   \newbibmacro*{name:given-family}[4]{%
     \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
       \ifprefchar
         {}
         {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}
   ```

   The similar macros `name:family` and `name:family-given` are used by other name formats.
   Commands like `\mkbibnamefamily` are used here, so that is the level at which your changes are ultimately applied. Since `name:family` and `name:family-given` are similar to `name:given-family` all of them use `\mkbibnamefamily`.

   You could define

   ```
   \DeclareNameFormat{given-family:bold}{%
     \let\mkbibnamefamily\mkbibbold
     \ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
   ```

   and then

   ```
   \DeclareNameAlias[article]{author}{given-family:bold}
   ```

   to affect only authors of `@article`s.

Comment: I could manage to get this piece of code working for the article. I'm now trying to make it work for my style on different entrytype and to reset the small caps on author/editor. Just a quick question how can I reset to a "plain" mode, i.e. what is the correct "\let\mkbibnamefamily\mkbib<standard>" ?

Comment: @XaWi The standard definitions are functionally equivalent to what you get from `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}`.

Comment: Sorry I was probably not clear. At the moment, I keep the french default "small caps", so my standard is "small caps". So what should I put in a name format like : \DeclareNameFormat{given-family:plain} ? I would then use the "\DeclareNameAlias[collection]{author}{given-family:plain}" in order to have plain, non-small caps author only for the collection item. Is it possible ?

Comment: @XaWi Not sure if I understand you correctly, but try `\let\mkbibnamefamily\@firstofone` instead of `\let\mkbibnamefamily\mkbibbold` in the code above. `\let\mkbibnamefamily\@firstofone` gives the same result as `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}` for most intents and purposes.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the formatting issue for the family name, but I'm having other issues. Do you mind if I open a new question on the collection/incollection ?

Comment: @XaWi Not at all. Just make sure that you have a good MWE ready, that it reproduces the error, and that the question explains your problem on a level that I can understand.